# Extension of the projective norm to a cross norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, matrix-analysis

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a finite-dimensional Hilbert space and $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ be an operator system. Is it possible to extend the projective norm (the greatest cross norm) of $\mathcal{A}\otimes M_n$ to a cross norm on $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})\otimes M_n$?

Any comment is highly appreciated. Please suggest to me some reference in case it exists in the literature.

Comment: Put the projective norm on $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)\otimes M_n$.  We know that the inclusion $\mathcal A\otimes M_n \rightarrow \mathcal B(\mathcal H)\otimes M_n$ is norm-decreasing.  But the projective norm is the _greatest_ crossnorm.  So if your question has a positive answer, the projective norm is the only choice, and we need to prove that the inclusion is an isometry...

Comment: @MatthewDaws I want to mention that the author of the https://msp.org/pjm/1967/22-1/pjm-v22-n1-p09-p.pdf (page 2, paragraph 2) wrote that Schatten has shown that for S, T, being subspace of U, V, the greatest cross norm topology on $U\otimes V$ is not an extension of the greatest cross norm topology on $S\otimes T$ in general.

Comment: Yes, exactly...  So this will not be automatic from general theory, but of course you are in a special case when it might (sometimes) be true.

Comment: @MatthewDaws I understand that if my question has a positive answer, say, $\Vert .\Vert$. Then for $a\in\mathcal{A}\otimes M_n$ we have $\Vert a\Vert=\Vert a\Vert_{\mathcal{A}\otimes M_n}=\Vert a\Vert_{\mathcal{B(\mathcal{H})}\otimes M_n}$. I do not understand why you are saying $\Vert .\Vert$ is necessarily the projective norm on $\mathcal{B(\mathcal{H})}\otimes M_n$. Could you please ellaborate?

Comment: @MatthewDaws I was trying to prove that the projection of $\mathcal{B}\mathcal{(H)}$ on $\mathcal{A}$ has norm less than or equal to $1$ using the special structure here, that is, $\mathcal{A}$ is an operator system and $\mathcal{H}$ is finite-dimensional Hilbert space which will imply $\mathcal{A}\otimes M_n\rightarrow\mathcal{B}\mathcal{(H)}\otimes M_n$ is isometric embedding. Unfortunately, I could not show it yet. Is there any other easy technique?

Comment: You should probably ask this as a new question.  But, immediately, I have no ideas in this direction.

Answer (score 2):

By request, some expansion of my easy comment.  Given normed spaces $E,F$ and $\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}u\in E\otimes F$ write $\pi(u; E\otimes F)$ for the projective norm of $u$ in $E\otimes F$.

The question asks if there is a crossnorm $\|\cdot\|$ on $\mc B(\mc H)\otimes M_n$ with
$$ \|u\| = \pi(u; \mc A\otimes M_n) \qquad (u\in\mc A\otimes M_n). $$
However, we know two things:

- $\|u \| \leq \pi(u; \mc B(\mc H)\otimes M_n)$ for any $u\in\mc B(\mc H)\otimes M_n$ because $\pi$ is the greatest crossnorm;
- $\pi(u; \mc B(\mc H)\otimes M_n) \leq \pi(u; \mc A\otimes M_n)$ by definition of the projective norm.

Putting these together gives
$$ \pi(u; \mc A\otimes M_n) = \|u\| \leq \pi(u; \mc B(\mc H)\otimes M_n)
\leq \pi(u; \mc A\otimes M_n) $$
for each $u\in\mc A\otimes M_n$.  So we have equality throughout, meaning:

- $\|\cdot\| = \pi(\cdot; \mc B(\mc H)\otimes M_n)$ on $\mc A\otimes M_n$;
- So the original question has a positive answer exactly when $\pi(u; \mc B(\mc H)\otimes M_n) = \pi(u; \mc A\otimes M_n)$ for all $u$.

That is, maybe there is some choice in $\|\cdot\|$ but that choice is unimportant, because if any crossnorm will work, the projective norm will work.

Comment: This was fine. But you said that if my question has a positive answer then $\Vert . \Vert$ has to be the projective norm on $\mathcal{B}\mathcal{(H)}\otimes M_n$. For that one also need to show $\pi(u; \mathcal{B}\mathcal{(H)}\otimes M_n)=\Vert u\Vert$ for all $u\in (\mathcal{A}\otimes M_n) ^c$, which is not clear to me. That is what I requested to ellaborate.

Comment: You are right, I was rather unclear here.  I'd adjusted my answer to hopefully make it (a) correct; and (b) less ambiguous.